# How to Parallelize Web Service Calls in a Spring Batch Job

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, spring-batch

I have a scheduled Spring Batch job that reads records from a PostgreSQL database. For each record, I make a web service call and store the response back into the database. Each web service call takes approximately 3 seconds to respond, so I'd like to parallelize these calls for efficiency.

Could anyone guide me on how to achieve this parallelization?

Code Snippets

Here's my configuration class, AsyncJobConfig.java, where I've modified the query to suit my needs.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ConditionalOnProperty(value="fiscal.operation.mode", havingValue="async")
public class AsyncJobConfig {
    @Autowired
    DocumentEntityItemWriterAsync documentEntityItemWriterAsync;
    @Autowired
    AsyncProcessor asyncProcessor;
    @Autowired
    private DocumentService documentService;
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactoryStatus;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactoryStatus;
    @Autowired
    private DocumentEntityRepository repository;
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AsyncJobConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("MAX_THREAD_GET_STATUS"))); // Set the number of threads you want to use
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("MAX_THREAD_GET_STATUS")));  // Set the maximum number of threads
        executor.setQueueCapacity(Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("MAX_THREAD_GET_STATUS"))); // Set the queue capacity for tasks waiting to be executed
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job statusJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactoryStatus
                .get("statusJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(initialDelayStep()) // Use a custom step for initial delay
                .next(statusStep()) // Continue with the actual processing step
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step initialDelayStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactoryStatus
                .get("initialDelayStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    Thread.sleep(Long.parseLong(System.getenv("MAX_SLEEP_ASYNC")));
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step statusStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactoryStatus
                .get("statusStep")
                .<DocumentEntity, DocumentEntity>chunk(20)
                .reader(statusReader())
                .processor(asyncProcessor)
                .writer(documentEntityItemWriterAsync)
                .taskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor()) // Set the taskExecutor
                .throttleLimit(Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("MAX_THREAD_GET_STATUS"))) // Set the number of threads to use concurrently
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<DocumentEntity> statusReader() {
        logger.info("Starting statusReader, async mode");
        JpaPagingItemReader<DocumentEntity> reader = new DocumentItemReaderAsync(repository);
        reader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        reader.setQueryString("select d from DocumentEntity d WHERE d.status = :status ");
        reader.setParameterValues(Collections.singletonMap("status", TBE_STATUS));
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Additionally, this is my reader class, DocumentItemReaderAsync.java, where I've also adjusted the query logic.

```
@StepScope
@Component
public class DocumentItemReaderAsync extends JpaPagingItemReader< DocumentEntity> {

    final private List< DocumentEntity> dataList=Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    private String status;
    private int index;
    @Autowired
    public DocumentItemReaderAsync(
            @Autowired
            DocumentEntityRepository repository) {
        this.index = 0;
        List<DocumentEntity> d = null;
        try {
            d = this.read0(repository);
            dataList.addAll(d);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Distinct query Error",e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private List<DocumentEntity> read0 (DocumentEntityRepository repository) {
    return repository.findByStatusTBE(TBE_STATUS) ;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public  DocumentEntity read() throws Exception {
        DocumentEntity documentEntity = null;
        synchronized(dataList)
        {

            //dataList = repository.myFindDistinct();

      //  DocumentEntity documentEntity = null;
        if( index < this.dataList.size()) documentEntity = dataList.get(index++);
        while (index < dataList.size() && dataList.get(index).getDocumentId().equals(documentEntity.getDocumentId())) {
            this.index++;
        }
        if (documentEntity == null) {
            dataList.clear();
            this.index = 0;
        }
        }
        return documentEntity;
    }

}
```

i tried with the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor but occurs 2 problem:

1. the query seems to be executed only the first time, the second, third ecc... is not executed since no records where processed
2. after some try if the query will be executed each time the batch starts seems like that all the records where given to all the thread opened
3. i tried to make a native query with the distinct but the problem of the 2° point occur anyway

Comment: I'm a bit confused as you're talking about processing things in parallel, but you're primarily talking about the `ItemReader`, which shouldn't happen in parallel right?

Comment: i am as confused as you are. i am not familiar with springboot so it could be completely wrong approach

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration already allows you to process the items in parallel.
However, processing should go in the `ItemProcessor` (in your case the `AsyncProcessor`). The best way to visualize this is by adding a log statement in your `AsyncProcessor`:

For example:

```
@Component
public class AsyncProcessor implements ItemProcessor<DocumentEntity, DocumentEntity> {
    @Override
    public DocumentEntity process(DocumentEntity entity) {
        log.info("Processing {}", entity.getId());
        // TODO: Send call to web service
        return entity;
    }
}
```

In the logs you'll see that the items are processed on different threads. For example:

```
INFO --- [ taskExecutor-1] x.y.z.AsyncProcessor   : Processing ...
INFO --- [ taskExecutor-2] x.y.z.AsyncProcessor   : Processing ...
INFO --- [ taskExecutor-3] x.y.z.AsyncProcessor   : Processing ...
INFO --- [ taskExecutor-4] x.y.z.AsyncProcessor   : Processing ...
```

Both your `DocumentItemReaderAsync` and DocumentItemWriterAsync` can actually stay synchronous.

What will happen is the following (simplified):

1. Spring Batch will read N amount of items from the database (`JpaPagingItemReader.doReadPage()`).
2. Spring Batch will keep reading until it can at least handle an entire chunk (your chunk size is `20`). So if you read 5 records from the database at once, it will call your `doReadPage()` method at least 4 times.
3. After that, Spring Batch will execute the `AsyncProcessor` for each individual item of the chunk. This processing is done on your `TaskExecutor`. This means that `MAX_THREAD_GET_STATUS` items are processed simultaneously.
4. After that, Spring Batch will collect the results of all those processed items until it has an entire chunk again, and send those off to the `ItemWriter`. You could use this for logging or saving the webservice result somewhere.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your response. However, the issue I'm encountering is that the records aren't being distributed among the open threads as expected.

To illustrate, let's say there are 100 records in the database. I anticipate that these records will be evenly distributed among the open threads. Unfortunately, the current behavior is such that all 100 records are assigned to the same thread that is open. In the logs, I have already printed the document IDs, and I have observed that they appear multiple times...

Comment: @SoxoS That's weird, in my dummy example (where I simply used `Thread.sleep()`  to simulate a webservice call) I can see that the processing is separated over multiple threads. Can you check what the `MAX_THREAD_GET_STATUS` value is? Also, where do you put the printing logic?